# Device tells us we need Google Play Services to Use Maps on Android device

Tags: api, google-maps, maps, google-play-services

we've been working with a 3rd party Android device that uses API 17.  We want to make a native Google API app so that we can map data for our customers.  What happens is the app crashes and it says "Google Play Services required".  Is there a workaround to this?  can we somehow embed or package a file that is good enough to use Maps?  We've spoken with the hardware company and they made a decision to not allow google play services.  We are partnering with them to release the device with a couple of apps we offer with the device.  Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Google Play services enables Maps to run on your Android devices, as per Google statement:

> With Google Play services, your app can take advantage of the latest,
>   Google-powered features such as Maps, Google+, and more, with
>   automatic platform updates distributed as an APK through the Google
>   Play store. This makes it faster for your users to receive updates and
>   easier for you to integrate the newest that Google has to offer.

That means you need Google Play services to make Google Maps work.

Download it [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en).

Comment: are you salesman?  That hasn't been working, that's why I'm asking how to make it work.  The device does not allow the google play store, but I somehow need to get it packaged in my app in order for it to work.  The device is hardware based and not a cellular phone made in Switzerland.  There are using apk 17 which is the highest they want to go with it.  ESRI maps works great on it, why is Google Maps limited to locking on google play services for no reason?